# Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 No such user here in C:\home\site\wwwroot\db_resp3.php on line 19

Tags: php, email, server, web, response

I am trying to write a simple php script to send an email.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('sendmail_from', 'mail@leslie4stateassembly.com');
   ini_set('SMTP', 'mail.leslie4stateassembly.com'); 
   ini_set('smtp_port', 25); 

   $recipient= "to2240@columbia.edu";
   $subject= "Example Email";
   $email= "Is this message gonna send!?!?";
   $headers=  "From:mail@leslie4stateassembly.com";

   $result = mail($recipient, $subject, $email, $headers);

  if ($result == false){
   echo "didn't send";
  }
   else {
    echo "sent";
   }
   echo phpinfo();
?>
```

I'm using the GearHost.com mail servers.  For some reason, I keep getting this response:

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 No such user here in C:\home\site\wwwroot\db_resp3.php on l

(for the record, I know that the recipient email address is correct.)
Please help!

Comment: Impossible to tell then from the code excerpt and error message. Could be all [sorts of things](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=550+No+such+user+here). Contact the recipient mail server admin for detailed logs. This question contains too little detail on the local MTA and remote MX. If you wanted some code advise however: [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](//stackoverflow.com/q/24644436)

Comment: I don't see any SMTP login information on your code. Don't u need a username/password to send emails via `leslie4stateassembly.com`? You may give a try to PHPMailer. Here's an SMTP example https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps